# The following packages have unmet dependencies (after switching from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center      
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5)
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Than I tried to install libsane:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsane
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And so on:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsnmp35
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsnmp35 : Depends: libsensors5 (>= 1:3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This error goes even farther. I also tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And this, but nothing helps:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove libsane
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libsane' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

EDIT:

```
$ sudo apt install libsensors5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsensors5 : Depends: libsensors-config but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

EDIT 2:

```
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for morlino: 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]     
Hit:3 http://ubuntu.mirror.vu.lt/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Get:4 http://ubuntu.mirror.vu.lt/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]       
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                             
Get:6 http://ubuntu.mirror.vu.lt/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]    
Get:7 http://ubuntu.mirror.vu.lt/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]      
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]       
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Get:12 http://ubuntu.mirror.vu.lt/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [102 kB]
Get:13 http://ubuntu.mirror.vu.lt/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [151 kB]
Get:14 http://ubuntu.mirror.vu.lt/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [532 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [532 B]
Get:16 http://ubuntu.mirror.vu.lt/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18.6 kB]
Get:17 http://ubuntu.mirror.vu.lt/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [31.6 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [31.6 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18.6 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [151 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [102 kB]
Fetched 1,232 kB in 2s (793 kB/s)                                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

EDIT 3:

```
$ sudo apt install libsensors-config
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-nlpsolver : Depends: default-jre (>= 2:1.8) but it is not going to be installed or
                                  java8-runtime or
                                  jre but it is not installable
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh : Depends: default-jre (>= 2:1.8) but it is not going to be installed or
                                            java8-runtime or
                                            jre but it is not installable
 libreoffice-script-provider-js : Depends: default-jre (>= 2:1.8) but it is not going to be installed or
                                           java8-runtime or
                                           jre but it is not installable
 libreoffice-wiki-publisher : Depends: default-jre (>= 2:1.8) but it is not going to be installed or
                                       java8-runtime or
                                       jre but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

EDIT 4:
It's just going deeper and deeper untill it says everything is newest version. But still, nothing is fixed. Maybe it'll be easier to just reinstall Ubuntu. But I'll wait for one more suggestion, thanks everyone

```
morlino@morlino:~$ sudo apt install libglx-mesa0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 20.0.4-2ubuntu1) but 20.2~git2006100730.2c711b~oibaf~b is to be installed
                Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
morlino@morlino:~$ sudo apt install libglapi-mesa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglapi-mesa is already the newest version (20.2~git2006100730.2c711b~oibaf~b).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
morlino@morlino:~$ sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 20.0.4-2ubuntu1) but 20.2~git2006100730.2c711b~oibaf~b is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
morlino@morlino:~$ sudo apt install libglapi-mesa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglapi-mesa is already the newest version (20.2~git2006100730.2c711b~oibaf~b).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Try to do `apt install libsensors5` to see what goes wrong with this dependancy.

Comment: Tried apt install libsensors5, it's the same

Comment: I didn't see you run `sudo apt update` anywhere and that may be a problem.

Comment: sudo apt update fixed nothing

Comment: Continue now by try to direct install libsensors-config (`apt install libsensors-config`), you will find what is conflicting...